# I have a problem trying to make a database request that has to do with location

Tags: php, mysql, json, database, laravel

I have a problem trying to make a database request that has to do with location, I'm using a google api for the geo location, and the idea is to sort from the closest to the furthest, but I'm getting one error and I don't know how to solve it

> ```
> $barbers = Barber::select(Barber::raw('*, SQRT(
>                     POW(69.1 * (latitude - '.$lat.'), 2 + 
>                     POW(69.1 * ('.$lng.' - longitude) * COS(latitude / 57.3), 2)) AS distance'))
>                     ->orderBy('distance', 'ASC')
>                     ->get();
> ```

Illuminate\Database\QueryException: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'from `barbers` order by `distance` asc' at line 3 (SQL: select *, SQRT(
POW(69.1 * (latitude - -23.5630907), 2 +
POW(69.1 * (-46.6682795 - longitude) * COS(latitude / 57.3), 2)) AS distance from `barbers` order by `distance` asc) in file C:\xampp\htdocs\ApiDevBarber\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php on line 692

Answer (score 0):

You were missing a closing parenthesis. It should be:

```
$barbers = Barber::select(Barber::raw('*, SQRT(
                POW(69.1 * (latitude - '.$lat.'), 2 + 
                POW(69.1 * ('.$lng.' - longitude) * COS(latitude / 57.3), 2))) AS distance'))
                ->orderBy('distance', 'ASC')
                ->get();
```

Are you trying to use the `c = sqrt(a^2 + b^2)` formula from Pythagoras? The formula you used looks like `c = sqrt(a^(b^2))`.

Comment: does not work, what solution do you propose?

Comment: @PedroGonçalves do you still get the same error?